# Is it grammatical and idiomatic to simplify this expression "the amount of that function that increases in this interval" this way?

Tags: sentence-construction, expressions

The lecturer is [saying](https://youtu.be/_9RGpiWjn_o?t=54)

> we can then say that the gradient of this line is equal to the amount of that function that increases in this interval
>   divided by the length of the interval

where the expression

```
the amount of that function that increases in this interval
```

is a little bit complex.

Is it grammatical and idiomatic and reasonable to simplify the expression as this

`the increased amount of that function in this interval`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably just a [slip of the tongue](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/slip-of-the-tongue) and he intended to say

> we can then say that the gradient of this line is equal to the amount that the function increases in this interval divided by the length of the interval